# My SwiftUI Button is not tappable for minus image systemName

Tags: swiftui, watchos

This is a fully reproducible example View to show the problem:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwitchView: View {
    @State private var timeMode = 1
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button {
                timeMode = 0
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "minus") //When I change to `plus` then everything is fine✅, but I need minus here.
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 24 , height: 24, alignment: .center)
            }
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(timeMode == 0 ? 1 : 0))
            .foregroundColor(timeMode == 0 ? Color.black : Color.gray)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
            Button {
                timeMode = 1
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 24 , height: 24, alignment: .center)
            }
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(timeMode == 1 ? 1 : 0))
            .foregroundColor(timeMode == 1 ? Color.black : Color.gray)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
        }
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.3))
        .cornerRadius(20)
    }
}

struct SwitchView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwitchView()
    }
}
```

[image]

`minus` button doesn't work correctly. It doesn't detect taps every time. Try to tap it above or below minus shape. When you tap on the simulator EXACTLY on the shape of `minus` then it works. But of course I want it to be tappable a whole `Button`, not just its shape.

Why does an image matter here? How can I find the issue?

Comment: The answer to this was supplied [24 days ago here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75322929/my-swiftui-button-doesnt-detect-tap-correctly-because-of-minus-image), though you had said it did not work. From Ashley Mills: "_Add `.contentShape(Ellipse())` to each button after the .frame modifier_". The solution below adds the method before the `.frame()` - could that make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell SwiftUI to consider the whole shape of the `Button` as tappable. This can be achieved using the modifier `.contentShape(...)`.

Here is how to use it:

```
            Button {
                timeMode = 0
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "minus") //When I change to `plus` then everything is fine✅, but I need minus here.
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 24 , height: 24, alignment: .center)
            }

            .contentShape(Rectangle())    // <- Here!!!

            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(timeMode == 0 ? 1 : 0))
            .foregroundColor(timeMode == 0 ? Color.black : Color.gray)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
```

The `Rectangle()` shape will also accept taps outside of the round corners of the minus button, so you could try using `Capsule()` or `Circle()` instead and see if it works better.

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt work. I dont undertstand why, but for some reason images with very flat shapes are not tappable inside Buttons. The solution was to change systemName from "minus" to "minus.circle.fill".

Comment: I can’t tell you why… it worked for me in the simulator.

Comment: It works in the simulator from time to time...;) not for every tap;)